# debhelper dh not rerunning when expected to

Tags: debian, packaging, deb, debhelper

I was converting some of my packages to use dh from the debhelper package, when I noticed that it doesn't support rerunning targets.

For example:

1. I run `debian/rules build` to check a build.
2. Make a small code change.
3. Run `debian/rules build` again, and it does nothing.

Or another common example I do:

1. I run `fakeroot debian/rules binary` to check if I have everything installed in the package correctly.
2. Find something missing; correct the problem.
3. Run `fakeroot debian/rules binary` to test out the change, and it does nothing.

This is a big change in behavior from CDBS, which I was previously using. Is there a work around for this? I don't feel like running `debian/rules clean` should be required in these situations.

debian/rules:

```
    #!/usr/bin/make -f

    export DEB_CXXFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND+=-std=gnu++0x

    %:
       dh $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's an intended and necessary behavior for `dh` (it has to keep track of what steps it has taken already, because it will usually be invoked several times over the course of a full package build and it can't leverage the internals of `make` to keep state. It's kind of a terrible hack, but it is a decent solution given the terrible problem constraints).

To be fair, it hasn't ever been well-defined what `debian/rules build` is supposed to do when there's already a partial build. If a build has succeeded previously and no state has been cleared, it's not unreasonable for Debhelper to treat the build as done.

It might be a solution to your problem just to use `dh_clean` when you want to start a build over. That won't invoke `dh_auto_clean`, so if your code gets built outside of the `debian/` directory, it won't be touched, but the Debhelper state will be cleaned.

If instead you want to be able to "rewind" the partial debhelper build so that it thinks a build hasn't yet been done, you might try using a script that does something like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sed -i -e '/dh_auto_build/,$ d' debian/*.debhelper.log
```

That will remove the "`dh_auto_build`" entry and everything after it from any *.debhelper.log build state, so that `dh` will think they haven't been done. Any steps it took up to that point will still be considered done.

Comment: This is unfortunate, but seems to be true.